# Different background speed jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, parallax

I made an paralax effect on my side.
Here its how it works:

1.One mousescroll=oneslide (Like here:[example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage))

2.Also I got menu for each slide (when you click it put you to clicked slide)

Now i need to rotate circles with different speed than the background.

For example when you scroll to next slide the circles must behave like that:
(the last position is when you are on the slide)
[image]

I know that its possible but how to do it?
Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Bq4/3/) code (but I dont know why in fiddle onemousescroll=oneslide doesnt work)

**JQ CODE:**

```
var counter = 1; //at slide
var amountOfSlides = 6;
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var currentPos = 0;

$('.paralax li').click(function() {

    var dataTarget=$(this).attr("data-target");
    var coll = $('.paralax li');
    var ktory = coll.index(this);
    currentPos=(-window.innerHeight*ktory);
    counter=ktory+1;

    document.getElementById('main').style.marginTop = currentPos + "px";

});
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', debounce(function(e) { 

    if(e.wheelDelta >= 0) {

        if(counter <= 1) return;
        currentPos = currentPos + window.innerHeight;
        counter--;

    } else {

        if(counter >= amountOfSlides) return;
        currentPos = currentPos - window.innerHeight;
        counter++;
    }
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginTop = currentPos + "px";


}, 250));

/
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    var timer = null;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            fn.apply(context, args);
        }, delay);
    };
}
```

Comment: There was a `/` on line 36 of your JSFiddle in the JS section and there was no `Library` selected on the left side. This is a working: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Bq4/9/) for your question, it doesn't solve it.